# Not sending email from form

Tags: php, email

I am just trying to make a script to send results from a form to me email. It WAS working but now its not even sending an email. Can anyone spot why?? thanks!! I have gone through this 100 times and I can not see what is wrong...

`

```
/* Subject and Email Variables */

$emailSubject = 'Membership Submission from Form';
$webMaster = 'testemail@gmail.com';

/* Gathering Data Variables */

$nameField = $_POST['name'];
$membershipField = $_POST['membership'];
$addressField = $_POST['address'];
$cityField = $_POST['city'];
$provinceField = $_POST['province'];
$postalcodeField = $_POST['postalcode'];
$telhomeField = $_POST['telhome'];
$telcellField = $_POST['telcell'];
$telofficeField = $_POST['teloffice'];
$emailField = $_POST['email'];
$commentsField = $_POST['comments'];

$body = <<<EOD
Name: $name <br>
Membership Type: $membership <br>
Address: $address <br>
City: $city <br>
Province: $province <br>
Postal Code: $postalcode <br>
Tel Home: $telhome <br>
Tel Cell: $telcell <br>
Tel Office: $teloffice <br>
Email: $email <br>
Comments: $comments <br>
EOD;


$headers = "from: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail ($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);

/* Results rendered as html */

$theResults = <<<EOD

EOD;
echo "$theResults";


?>`
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Where's the `form` html code?

Comment: Have you tried a different email address? Gmail has some issues with PHP-generated emails, so they could be ending up in spam. Try a Hotmail / Yahoo / etc one, just to see if that's the issue.

Comment: *"It WAS working"* --- Did you not keep a working copy of your code?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `EOT` when there is a variable within thr string. `EOD` is for strings that do not contain variables, unless i am mistaken.

Comment: Try changing `$headers = "from: $email\r\n";` to `$headers = "From: $email\r\n";` --- maybe that lowercase `f` in `from` might not work. I've seen stranger things happen. And get rid of that space in `mail ($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);` as in `mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);`

Comment: @Vector The identifier choice doesn't affect the way heredoc syntax works

Comment: Plus change `$headers = "from: $email\r\n";` to `$headers = "from: $emailField\r\n";` also `Email: $email <br>` to `Email: $emailField <br>`

Comment: Errors = "notice: variable `$success' assigned but never used" . It is not the gmail thing I have tried multiple email addresses...it is not even sending an email so I dont think it is the variable thing..

Comment: @Emperor12 Then delete `$success =` altogether and keep the rest just to test so the line now reads as `mail ($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);` --- `$success` would probably need to be passed as an `if` inside a function.

Comment: @Emperor12 - can you `var_dump($success)` to see if your mail is actually sent? Do you have access to the SMTP server's logs to see what's happening there?

Comment: I just put the full name (with Field) on each and now it works... thanks guys.

Comment: @Emperor12 *"I just put the full name (with Field) on each and now it works"* --- If this is in regards to your form, then if you do have a similar problem in the future, might I suggest you post your form as well (right off the bat)? That is a **"crucial part"** of a question. Just like what [**Vector asked at the beginning**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365828/not-sending-email-from-form#comment26965866_18365828)

Comment: @Fred-ii- - if you look at the form, the variables he's assigning are called `$nameField`, `$membershipField`, and so on; but the email was using `$name`, `$membership`. I _think_ what he means is that he swapped over the variables in the email and it now works, though I can't for the life of me see what difference that might have made to why an email wasn't being sent.

Comment: @andrewsi Questions like these tend to have people run all over the place. When the form is omitted from the question, leaves a lot of room for confusion.